# Unable to ask this question

Tags: support, suggested-edits, reject

I am unable to submit this question, it is not up to standards, as the fourm says...

> I am looking for a battery for a laptop from japan, says "PC-ns750aag-e3" on the back.
>
> I am having trouble, as i don't understand japanese...
>
> Is there a location i need to look?

Comment: Can you suggest some edits so i can post it?

Comment: Your question isn’t within scope, so edits, wouldn’t make it an acceptable question.  Great chat question though

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're getting "It does not meet our quality standards." That means you need to improve upon your question; the easiest way to do so in your case is to add more relevant information to the post. For more information, see [this Meta Stack Exchange question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards).

That said, [shopping recommendation questions are off-topic for Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), so your question would be closed anyway had it been allowed. As things are, I wouldn't try to ask the question on the main site at all; instead, you might want to discuss it in our main chat room, [Root Access](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access).

Answer (score 0):

Questions about shopping are off-topic for the main board. This question will never be okay.

That being said, you are probably looking for this battery:

http://nec-lavie.jp/shop/necoption/PC-VP-WP125.html

Pro Tip: Use Google Chromes built in Translate Page function to get around the pesky trouble of not being able to read Japanese. ;)